# sql server 2005 database password recovery

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, passwords

i have one database in ms sql server 2005.

i create this long time back, now want to modify it but i lost the password, i remember the user name for that database, is there any way to recover the password for that database or

change its password ?

Thanks

Comment: as far i know the sql server databases does not support passwords.

Comment: Put the server into Windows auth mode, then login as a local machine user. From there you should be able to do whatever you need to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Databases don't have passwords. You may be talking about:

- the password of a database master key, certificate or other cryptographic key encrypted by password
- the password of a SQL Server login
- the password of database backup media

None of these can be recovered if lost. The only one that can be brute forced is if you lost access to a SQL instance, see [How to add a Windows user to the sysadmin fixed server role in SQL Server 2005 as a failure recovery mechanism](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/937682)